# HighCharts Bubble Chart: text for axis interval labels

Tags: highcharts

I trying to use HighCharts to display the number of males and females in the various age groups for 3 cities.

I thought a Bubble chart would be perfect.
x-axis: Male, Female
y-axis: Age groups (0-10 years, 11-20 years, 21-30 years and above 30)
series: the 3 cities
bubble size: number of people

The problem is that both x and y axis require numbers for the axis intervals and not text.
So I changed my chart data to return 0 & 1 for female and male 
and numbered each Age Group (where 1 = 0-10 years, 2 = 11-20 years etc.)

Now the chart works fine but off course the axis interval labels are meaningless.
Is there a way that I can change the labels to text?

So for the purpose of generating the chart, I can use 0 & 1 but for the interval labels I would like it to display "female" and "male".

I searched quite a bit, but could only find ways to customize the tooltip.

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle of what you have so far?  Or at the least post some code/picture?  I'm having a hard time visualizing how you want the chart to look.

Comment: Hi Mark. I guess my questions can be simplified to; A bubble chart requires the x and y axis labels to be numbers. Is there a way to have text as opposed to numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your chart code, it's not easy to say the best way to solve this.

The first option I would look at is using x-axis categories.

An alternative option may be to do this using the axis labelformatter function (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter).

For your case, you could do something like:

```
function() {
      if (this.value === 1) {
        return "female";
      } else {
        return "male";
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Steve. I went the label formatter route.